# Unable to open Gurobi license file.Why the start of path has '?'?

Tags: python, gurobi

[Unable to open Gurobi license file.Why the start of path has '?' ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN6nu.png)

```
File "src\gurobipy\gurobi.pxi", line 3575, in gurobipy.read File
      "src\gurobipy\gurobi.pxi", line 84, in gurobipy.gurobi.read File
      "src\gurobipy\gurobi.pxi", line 32, in gurobipy.gurobi._getdefaultenv
      File "src\gurobipy\env.pxi", line 62, in gurobipy.Env.__init__
    gurobipy.GurobiError: Unable to open Gurobi license file
    '?C:\Users\GIGABYTE\gurobi.lic'
```

Comment: What is the code that produces this issue?

Comment: An error occurred after installing gurobi. The license file cannot be opened in the error prompted. There is a '?' at the beginning of the license file path.

Comment: So this is just during installation then. The `?` doesn't matter here, probably (maybe they put it there as output, whatever) - the important question is do you have a `gurobi.lic`? Because it needs to be put in the right location for Gurobi to run.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question and could be better addressed by contacting Gurobi support at support.gurobi.com.

Comment: My guess is that this is an issue with a non-Western language on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the installation of gurobi in the virtual environment is not activated, and it can run successfully after activation